# Where is NbSortDirection, NbSortRequest from @nebular/theme?

Tags: angular, nebular

I am getting syntax errors for the import below. Can someone tell how to fix this?

```
All imports in import declaration are unused.ts(6192)
```

Module '"../../../../../../../../Users/denisputnam/git/nb-niche-app/node_modules/@nebular/theme"' has no exported member 'NbSortDirection'. Did you mean 'NbLayoutDirection'?ts(2724)
direction.service.d.ts(6, 21): 'NbLayoutDirection' is declared here.

```
import { NbSortDirection, NbSortRequest, NbTreeGridDataSource, NbTreeGridDataSourceBuilder } from '@nebular/theme';

enter code     import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NbSortDirection, NbSortRequest, NbTreeGridDataSource, NbTreeGridDataSourceBuilder } from '@nebular/theme';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkpoint-criteria',
  templateUrl: './checkpoint-criteria.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkpoint-criteria.component.scss']
})
export class CheckpointCriteriaComponent implements OnInit {
  customColumn = 'name';
  defaultColumns = [ 'size', 'kind', 'items' ];
  allColumns = [ this.customColumn, ...this.defaultColumns ];

  dataSource: NbTreeGridDataSource<any>;

  sortColumn: string = '';
  sortDirection: NbSortDirection = NbSortDirection.NONE;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine on my side, here's an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-7y2b27?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts. Just make sure `@nebular/theme` version is on `3.4.0` at least.

Comment: I had an older version.  Thank you.